# Persistently unique AssemblyName on every build

Tags: msbuild, csproj

I have a simple solution with one dll project (hot-reloading it elsewhere).

I need the AssemblyName to be unique on every build (due to the way I'm doing the hot reloading, in the same app domain).

However, I also need the AssemblyName to stay the same until right before the next build, so I can debug (dll identity is established based on AssemblyName).

I've been using something that was updating the AssemblyName in the csproj with the current ticks. However, that fails my second requirement - doing various things in the project (not necessarily rebuilding) refreshes the AssemblyName inside the IDE (I'm using Rider).

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

We need two points:

1. Change the assembly name only on `Release`.
2. Generate a unique name for the assembly.

### Change the AssemblyName only on `release`

The name of the assembly configured in `.csproj` file, with tag `AssemblyName`, in [`PropertyGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/propertygroup-element-msbuild?view=vs-2017#example) section.

For changing the name only for **Release** we need to add contidion to PropertyGroup:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
  <AssemblyName>MyCustomOrDefaultAssemblyName</AssemblyName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

### Generate a unique name for the assembly

We use [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions) for getting a unique name:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
  <CurrentDate>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString(yyyyMMdd-mmss))</CurrentDate>
  <AssemblyName>MyCustom$(CurrentDate)</AssemblyName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

We can also inject the name from outside. If we do the build from the command line, we can inject the property by adding [`/p:name=value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference) to the build command, and use the property as AssemblyName:

**csproj file:**

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
  <AssemblyName>$(GeneratedProperty)</AssemblyName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Command line:**

```
MSBuild /t:Build /p:GeneratedProperty=%TIME:~0,2%.%TIME:~3,2%
dotnet build -c Release -p:GeneratedProperty=%TIME:~0,2%.%TIME:~3,2%
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but this doesn't address my issue. Why constrain it to just release? For the second part, the generation of the unique name will happen every time the csproj is reevaluated, which is too aggressive.

Comment: I still can't figure out what your problem is. `need the AssemblyName to stay the same until right before the next build`, can you explain?

Comment: Debugging works based on assembly identity (which in turn depends on AssemblyName). I don't just need the dll name to be different, I need it to stay the same until next time I build. I other words, I'm trying to automate this workflow: "change code, change assembly name, build". With your approach (and my initial approach) the worfklow would be more like "change code, change assembly name, build, change assembly name, change assembly name". I can't figure out when the .csproj file get reevaluated, but for example that happens when going into its properties (right click->properties in Rider).